# Write JSX outside of a React component (and still transform it into a ReactElement)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to define a bunch of data in a constants file which will be used to render a series of React components, including some HTML, which I'd like to be able to write in JSX. Below is a simplified example of what I'd like to do:

```
// constants.ts
export interface ItemInfo {
  title: string;
  description: React.ReactElement; // Or whatever this type should be. Just trying to get it working for now, can figure out correct typing later.
}

export const DATA: ItemInfo[] = [
  {
    title: 'Foo',
    // Pseudo code below, how can I get this working?
    description: (
      <>
        <p>Some JSX.</p>
        <p>To be rendered in a React component.</p>
      </>
    ),
  },
  {
    title: 'Bar',
    description: (
      <>
        <p>More JSX.</p>
        <p>To be rendered in a React component.</p>
      </>
    ),
  },
  // etc
];
```

```
// ItemComponent.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { ItemInfo } from './constants';

const ItemComponent: FC<ItemInfo> = ({title, description}) => (
  <div>
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <div>{description}</div>
  </div>
);
```

```
// ListComponent.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { ItemInfo } from './constants';

const ListComponent: FC<ItemInfo[]> = ({items}) => (
  <div>
    {items.map((item) => <ItemComponent {...item} />)}
  </div>
);
```

I'm using TypeScript, so I've done the simplified example above in TS as well, though I don't think it should matter. I've tried importing React in the `constants.ts` file, and using `React.createElement()` on the JSX, but to no avail. I can just move the `DATA` constant inside of the `ListComponent`, in which case everything works, but I want to decouple the data from the component, so that it can be used to render different lists of data in different places.

I'm open to suggestions about avoiding using this pattern (in which case please offer reasons why and alternatives), but if it is possible to do this I'd still also like to know how in addition to knowing why I shouldn't and what I should do instead :)

Any insights appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, actually I just figured it out. All I had to do was change the `constants.ts` file to a `constants.tsx` file.

I'll leave this question up in case it's helpful to anyone else since I didn't find great results when Googling this question (probably because it was such an obvious mistake haha).

If anyone does have comments on whether and why this pattern should or shouldn't be used, I am also still interested.